# I'm slower than a sloth

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm slower than a sloth, yet have been known to travel faster than sound. Printers think I'm good for nothing yet bartenders charge good money for me. What am I?

The answer is a single English word. It can be found in any ordinary dictionary. No hyphens no trickery. No proper names fictional or non-fictional. Just an ordinary word. Not an abstract noun or nebulous concept. You can see and touch these just like you could, say, a tennis ball or a table (These objects aren't clues, they're just random examples of tangible objects).

Note: "Slower than a sloth" should be taken to relate to a race between me and the sloth. We would both move under our own power at our fastest speed towards the finishing line but the sloth would win.

Comment: I've reopened the question based on the current edits (and cleaned up the comments here), since it might not have gotten enough activity to be reopened otherwise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it:

> slug

---

slower than a sloth

> slugs (the animal) are known to move slowly.

faster than sound

> "slug" can also refer to a bullet.

printers

> in typesetting, the "slug" is an area that contains instructions for the printer, but is trimmed off and discarded after a document is printed.

bartenders

> a "slug" also means a shot of an alcoholic drink.

Comment: This is correct in every respect except for a quibble about the printer. Could you back up your assertion (with a URL to the relevant explanation)  that it refers to an error? I don't think it does. If you can do that (or come up with a better explanation) I'll gladly accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK is this your intended answer?  Or you had something else in your mind actually

Comment: here: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/slugarea.htm 
"A slug area is the name used to describe the area outside the printing area and bleed area of a document that contains the registration mark and other printing instructions for the printer." Nice answer!

Comment: @Alex B - Yes slug is my intended answer!  I can back up all the facts with the correct references if necessary.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I was using the 11th definition [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slug#Noun) but the definition Doge linked seems to be better-attested.

Comment: Okay, I'm accepting it. Here is my definition. "In one sense, a ---- is a piece of spacing material used to space paragraphs." http://goo.gl/40KaAw - Therefore, when printing, the ---- shows up as empty space, or in the terms of the riddle, 'nothing'

Answer (score 5):

Got it! It's a

> slug

Slower than a sloth:

> Slugs travel up to 0.01 m/s, sloths about 0.03 m/s on the ground.

Faster than sound:

> Bullets are called slugs too, and most of them travel faster than sound.

Printers think I'm good for nothing:

> [Slugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(typesetting)) are used in printing to space paragraphs, so are in a sense good for "nothing" (space.)

Bartenders charge good money for me:

> A slug is also a shot of liquor.

Comment: Shoot, did not see the newer answer!

Comment: Haha! - Pity because you got all the clues spot on!

Answer (score 4):

Okay, probably not the real answer, but is it a:

> shot

Slower than a sloth:

> Very literally, shot is the pellets in a shotgun or the ball tossed by a shotputter. They're inanimate so they don't move at all.

Faster than sound:

> Most guns shoot bullets faster than sound.

Printers think I'm good for nothing:

> (This is a stretch.) Printers are interested in words, not pictures. They would prefer a good page of well-typeset text to your *shot* of the same subject.

And of course, bartenders charge good money for me!

Comment: Why the downvote, downvoter?  Seems the answer is explained adequately.

Comment: P.S. I wasn't the down-voter. Yours is the best attempt so far IMHO.  Most of it is plausible but you missed my note that says, "*Note: "Slower than a sloth" should be taken to relate to a race between me and the sloth. The sloth would win.*" I don't see how an inanimate object can reasonably take part in a race. I've made that explicit now.  Also I don't think the printer one is very convincing.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep thinking...

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> water ?

Race (speculative):

> Depending on the landscape it would flow towards the finishing line, but extremely slow, so a sloth could win.

Faster than sound:

> There are waterjet cutter. But i honestly don't know how fast the water will get there.

Printer:

> Water destroys the work of printers or make them nearly useless if the paper is soaked.

Bartender:

> Water is sometimes more expensive than other drinks